# Formal language properties and finite state machines

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, closure-properties, nondeterminism

What are properties of a formal language? Which and how would they be needed to prove that some Non-Deterministic finite state machine can accept a given language?

Comment: A formal language is just a set of strings, so I don't think that's what you mean to ask. Our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/9550) cover the rest of your question (see the section on formal languages).

Comment: Look at Myhill-Nerode theorem, which is a characterization in terms of language property of languages accepted by finite state machines (usually called finite automata). The languages are called regular languages. They can also be characterized by closure properties (see regular expressions).

Comment: I like the way this question is asked. It is a bit a pity to close it. Actually, the issue is more properties of families of languages, but that is not obvious to grasp for a beginner.